# Importing and running a standalone React application inside a web component

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I have a standalone React application that uses webpack for bundling with a requirement of being able to run this bundle within a web component. Can anyone suggest how I should approach this?

I'm thinking something like:

```
//webpack.config.js
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        library: 'reactUmd',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },

//react-component.js
import '../../packages/react-umd/dist/bundle.js'

class ReactComponent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(mountPoint);
    reactUmd.renderSomeComponentTo(mountPoint)
  }
}

customElements.define('react-component', ReactComponent)
```

But I'm not sure how I can import the compiled bundle and get a reference to React, ReactDOM, the Main component etc, would exporting as UMD provide the references I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to access the react component outside the minified bundle file.

Here is one approach:

- You tell webpack to [create a library](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) for your file. This will basically create a global variable using which you can access all the exported functions from you js entry file. 
  To do so, add a key called `library` int your webpack config under `output` object.

  `module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
      library: 'someLibName'
    },
    ...
  }`
- After doing this, restart your webpack server and on console, type window.someLibName. This should print all the methods exported by `main.js` as an object.
- Next step is to create a function which accepts a DOM element and [renders the react component on the element](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render). The function would look something like this:

  `export const renderSomeComponentTo = (mountNode) => {
    return ReactDOM.render(<App />,MOUNT_NODE);
  }`
- Now you can access the above function from anywhere in the project, using

  `const mountNode = document.getElementById('theNodeID');
  window.someLibName.renderSomeComponentTo(mountNode);`

This way, all the react specific code is abstracted :)

I hope I answered your question. Don't forget to hit star and upvote. Cheers

Comment: Hey Rahul,

So I've tried to follow your steps but having no success, I've added additional properties to my webpack config:

library: reactUmd,
libraryTarget: umd,
umdNamedDefine: true

I've created a function in the react project called renderSomeComponentTo that will take the mountNode

The problem is that when I try to call reactUmd.renderSomeComponentTo(mountNode)  I get error Uncaught TypeError: reactUmd.renderSomeComponentTo is not a function

I've updated question with my latest

Comment: When I console.log(window.reactUmd) I only see Object {__esModule: true}, I don't seem to have access to any functions.

Comment: Hey Rahul, I've managed to import my react component into the web component - the issue I'm coming up against now is that I have no react bindings within the component?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue?
What kind of react bindings?
Can you paste the error here?